# DELETE statements must restrict all PRIMARY KEY columns with equality relations in order to delete non static columns

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax

If i understand this statement correctly

```
DELETE statements must restrict all PRIMARY KEY columns with equality relations in order to delete non static columns
```

it states that all my primary key should have equality symbol i.e `=`

here is the query i'm using to delete

```
DELETE FROM service.data WHERE product_uuid=432523b3-8094-4a0d-b93a-cc8d22100f85 AND item_uuid=a709c5cc-8f98-4cba-b1dc-264b0fd24e08 IF EXISTS;
```

how is the query wrong?? what is the correct one to delete a row from data table??

Comment: what is the structure of the primary key? why do you need `IF EXISTS`?

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY definition?